# How to calculate sum if using repeater

Tags: c#, html

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        String cquery = "SELECT cart.ProductID, ProName, Size, Colour, Price  FROM cart, Products WHERE Custid=" + Session[custid] + "AND Products.ProductID = cart.ProductID";
        SqlCommand ccmd = new SqlCommand(cquery, con);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        CRepeater.DataSource = ccmd.ExecuteReader();
        CRepeater.DataBind();
        con.Close();
        DataRow[] dr = dataTable.Select("SUM(Price)");
        Label3.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[0]); ;
```

I am using a repeater to display data from database and i cant seem to figure out how to get the sum using repeater

Comment: please [don't post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please add code, not picture. Explain what you have tried so to *figure out how to get the sum using repeater*

Comment: Code shared via image is not readable. Please share code in the question itself. Where is repeater in your code?

Comment: Codes My Man .... Without them we make out what went wrong. Make sure u always post your questions with codes

Comment: 3rd line u miss some space in ur cquery at: `...Where Custid="*here*` and `*here*AND Products...`

Comment: You also shouldn't be concatenating strings into SQL like that for `Session[custid]`, as that's how SQL injection attacks happen. Better to use a named parameter (or anonymous one, depending on which DB driver you're using) and a SqlParameter. Although I'd guess you're safe here if there's no way a user can influence the value of their customer ID string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best approach to calculate the sum of a column in a DataTable use the DataTable.Compute method.

```
// Declare an object variable.
object sumObject;
sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Price)", "");
```

Display the result in your Total Amount Label like so:

```
Label3.Text = sumObject.ToString();
```

**Update**

your missing to load the DataTable,try this

```
 var dataReader = ccmd.ExecuteReader();
 var dataTable = new DataTable();
 dataTable.Load(dataReader);
 CRepeater.DataSource = dataTable;
 CRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: it says that that column price does not exist

Comment: It looks like you're creating a DataTable but then not loading the data into it. Can you get the DataTable from the CRepeater to query instead?

Comment: Please check my update,I have updated based on @Rub comment

Comment: sorry, but how do i that?